# Is it impossible to tell if a function is a generator function if .bind() has been called on it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, ecmascript-harmony

Looks like calling .bind(this) on any generator function breaks my ability to see if the function is a generator. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
var isGenerator = function(fn) {
    if(!fn) {
        return false;
    }

    var isGenerator = false;

    // Faster method first
    // Calling .bind(this) causes fn.constructor.name to be 'Function'
    if(fn.constructor.name === 'GeneratorFunction') {
        isGenerator = true;
    }
    // Slower method second
    // Calling .bind(this) causes this test to fail
    else if(/^function\s*\*/.test(fn.toString())) {
        isGenerator = true;
    }

    return isGenerator;
}

var myGenerator = function*() {
}

var myBoundGenerator = myGenerator.bind(this);

isGenerator(myBoundGenerator); // false, should be true
```

Comment: bind() returns a new function. a plain function, with no ties to the past

Comment: Maybe this would be of interest to see how they do it: https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-bind

Comment: possible duplicate of [check if function is a generator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754956/check-if-function-is-a-generator)

Comment: @Kirk - I turned my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `.bind()` returns a new (stub) function that only just calls the original with `.apply()` in order to attach the proper `this` value, it is obviously no longer your generator and that is the source of your issue.

There is a solution in this node module: https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-bind.

You can either use that module as is or see how they solve it (basically they make the new function that `.bind()` returns also be a generator).

Comment: A bound generator is still a generator, as can be tested with yield*. I posted my answer below. (to be fair, it is possible that a correction was made since 1.5 years ago)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to tell if a function is a generator even if .bind() has been called on it:

```
function testIsGen(f) {
  return Object.getPrototypeOf(f) === Object.getPrototypeOf(function*() {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This package has the solution:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-bind

Basically, in order to get it to work you either need to polyfill Function.prototype.bind or call a custom bind() method.