# UglifyJS property mangling

Tags: javascript, node.js, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

According to the docs, UglifyJS can mangle all property names except those on a provided reserved list. Is it possible to do it the other way, so only properties on provided list will be mangled?

If so, what options do I need to pass to `uglify.minify(files, { ... })`?

Comment: it seems such option is not supported so you would need to modify source code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One (ugly) command-line approach to achieve the kind of whitelist you're looking for might be to use the regex option.

> You can also use a regular expression to define which property names should be mangled. For example, --mangle-regex="/^_/" will only mangle property names that start with an underscore.

[UglifyJS2 Readme](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2)

Otherwise, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/690) which provides the code you could use to modify uglify yourself which achieves what I believe you're looking for.

Comment: Can you somehow do the opposite? Like say that you mangle all the properties except the ones that start with an underscore?