# ES6 creating new instance with reflection

Tags: javascript, reflection, ecmascript-6

I have a use case where I need to persist the name of a given class in a cookie so that I can create an instance of it later when the client returns. I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
class MyClass {
}

var a1 = new MyClass()
var className = a.class.name()//like in Java..
var a2 = Class.forName(className).newInstance();
```

Is this possible in ES6? Specifically I am looking for some way to get the name fo the class as a string,

Comment: I don't think this question should be down vote. It's not bad question or seem duplicated exactly. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the name of the class by calling `a1.constructor.name`[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30560581/1589521)

Since classes are really fancy syntax for functions, if the class exists on the window object you could probably then do something like `var a2 = new window[className]();` but that really depends what scope you are working in.