# UglifyJS - Mangle functions but preserve Function.prototype.name

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6, uglifyjs

When using UglifyJS, function names are mangled, unless `keep_fnames` is set to `true`. For example, the following Typescript code:

```
class Test {}
console.log(Test.name);
```

compiled to JS as:

```
function Test() {}
console.log(Test.name);
```

will be uglified to:

```
function t() {}
console.log(t.name);
```

and output `t` instead of `test` to the console.

Is there a way ([**other than using `keep_fnames` option**](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/1429)) to preserve the `name` property after uglification ? (I don't want to use `keep_fnames:true` because it increases the bundle size quite a lot.

Possible solutions I thought of:

- Writing a Webpack plugin that hard codes the function name `Test.name = 'Test'`, but this won't work as `Function.prototype.name` is a read only property;
- Using Typescript decorators, metadata and the reflection API, but `design:type` metadata is not emitted for classes, it's only emitted for properties (which I believe is because `Function.prototype.name` exists, but I guess they missed this edge case ?).

Comment: Can you write a Webpack plugin that replaces instances of `Test.name` with `"Test"`? Similar to what the `DefinePlugin` does.

Comment: I guess yes, but in this case I simplified the example. In my real use case, the `.name` property is accessed from within an external library that I wrote as a private npm package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46561116/angular4-component-name-doesnt-work-on-production

Comment: @user5365075 What does this library need the `.name` for?

Comment: This library uses class names to create a service registry, and also to inject those services in other services and classes. Providing a service ID does not solve anything because the lib also relies on `.name` to get the types to inject. Mangling replaces function names and thus corrupts typescript metadata, which does not store string type values but references to the class (which becomes a function when compiled).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46561116/angular4-component-name-doesnt-work-on-production/46561297), `Function.prototype.name` cannot be relied on in client-side code, because the information on function original name will be destroyed with minification process. Preventing it from being renamed is quick-and-dirty fix.

`name` is read-only and non-configurable in some browsers, so doing something like

```
class Test {
  static get name() {
    return 'Test';
  }
}
```

or

```
function Test() {}
Object.defineProperty(Test, 'name', { configurable: true, value: 'Test' });
```

will fix it in most browsers but result in obscure compatibility problems in rest of them (for example, Android 4.x browser).

The proper way to do this is to *never rely on `name` in client-side code* for anything but debugging. As for Node.js and Electron, it depends on whether the code needs to be obfuscated.

If string identifier should exist for a class or a function, another static property name can be picked, e.g. `id` or unsupported yet conventional [`displayName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/displayName).

Comment: Great answer, honestly. I like the idea of using `displayName`. Too bad it is an unavoidable workaround.

Comment: You're welcome. Unavoidable, yes. Notice that situation with `name` isn't same as with props for `design:type`. Props have fixed names (they can be mangled by minifier too, but this is hardly ever desirable). Functions don't.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way (other than using keep_fnames option) to preserve the name property after uglification...

The only mechanism to keep the correct name involves that name being in the output file, so the short answer is no. If you want to use `prototype.name` you need to leave that name be.

The alternatives would involve either:

1. Adding an additional property containing the name, which could introduce errors and would still take up space in your file
2. Finding a tool that will pre-compile all uses of `prototype.name` with the string value... I'm not aware that one exists but you never know!

Comment: Option 2 I like very much :) I guess writing such a webpack plugin is doable, but I am worried that this won't work in this case because my code that uses the function name is contained in an external library. Hence, `.name` is access in an external library.

Comment: It would be terribly hard to resolve some uses, and of course potentially impossible if the usage would be different in multiple cases (which is presumably the case, otherwise you wouldn't be looking at the value).