# How to access variable name assigned to object from within class constructor in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, this, setattribute

I want to write the constructor so that every time the object is called, the CSS properties are created using the name of variable that is assigned to the new class instance, plus a unique string. Like so:

```
class BigBox{

    constructor(){

        var div_box = document.createElement("div");
        div_box.setAttribute("id", this."_title");
        document.body.appendChild(div_box); 
    }

}


var S1 = new BigBox();
```

So in the above example, the aim is to set the id to be **S1_title**, it is not working however. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310530/get-the-class-name-of-es6-class-instance

Comment: You need to instantiate a class using the `new` keyword: `var S1 = new BigBox()`

Comment: Thanks. Fixed that but still not working.

Comment: Hi. `this."_title"` isn't valid javascript, or at least I'm having problems getting it to run in my console.

Comment: I think it is not possible and also a very bad practice, variables naming should not affect the execution of your code. You should just pass a string to the constructor and use it for naming the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a bad idea, it is better to just pass the title to the constructor.

```
class BigBox{

    constructor(title){

        var div_box = document.createElement("div");
        div_box.setAttribute("id", this."_title");
        document.body.appendChild(div_box); 
    }

}


var S1 = new BigBox("S1");
```