# How to check if a variable is a generator function? (e.g function* yield)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Whats a reliable way to check if a function is a generator, e.g.:

```
let fn = function* () {
    yield 100;
}

if (fn instanceof ??) {
   for (let value in fn()) {
       ...
   }
}
```

The only way I can think of is `fn.toString().startsWith('function*')` but that's extremely hacky and unreliable

context: nodejs 4+

Comment: Maybe you could check if `next` is defined on it?

Comment: Just tried, typeof fn.next is "undefined"

Comment: You could probably do something like `if(typeof fn().next === 'function') {}`

Comment: That's not an *iterator* function, that's a *generator* function.

Comment: @saadq: But that would mis-identify any function returning an object with a `next` method.

Comment: check `fn.constructor.name == "GeneratorFunction"`

Comment: Yep, it's definitely not a good way to do it. That was just meant to explain that he was supposed to be doing `next()` instead of `next`.

Comment: @JaromandaX: It's a good thought, esp. for the contained environment (e.g., just has to work for V8). **But**, sadly, A) People mess up the `constructor` property all the time, you can't rely on it for basically anything if you're testing a function that isn't your own code. And B) It's possible to have a function called `GeneratorFunction`, which would lead to mis-identification...

Comment: what about the added test that `fn().next.prototype === undefined`

Comment: @JaromandaX: All arrow functions have `.prototype === undefined`, so if `fn` returns an object with a `next` method that's an arrow function... Separately, that check would require calling the function in order to find out what it is.

Comment: @bergi: Nice catch on it being a dupe, I frankly didn't think to look, given how relatively new this stuff is.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Yeah, the dupe is only over 2 years old :-) We've got many questions on how to distinguish all the new ES6 function types already, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31936822/1048572) might become a suitable canonical maybe (with some work)

Comment: @ChrisBarrett: I've updated my answer, there *is* a better way -- and yet, the check probably doesn't tell you anything meaningful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Erik Arvidsson makes a good point in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19660350/157247) to an earlier version of this question (it didn't occur to me that it's a dupe), that since any function can return an iterator, there's little point in checking whether a function is a generator or not. That is, there's not much you can do with the information in practical terms, since non-generators can return iterators.

---

I was wrong before, there *is* a better way than your `toString` check (if for some reason you have a valid need to do it at all):

1. (Once) Get the value of the default `constructor` of a generator function, which is [specified here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-generatorfunction.prototype.constructor). It doesn't have a global like `Function` and such do.
2. (Whenever you need to check) Check to see if your target function is `instanceof` that generator function constructor.

E.g.:

```
// Once
var GeneratorFunction = (function*(){}).constructor;

// Whenever you need to check
if (fn instanceof GeneratorFunction) {
    // Yep, it's a generator function
}
```

---

Old things ruled out:

I don't see anything in the specification that lets us directly access the `[[FunctionKind]]` internal slot.

The spec [does say](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-generatorfunction-instances-prototype):

> Unlike function instances, the object that is the value of the a GeneratorFunction’s `prototype` property does not have a `constructor` property whose value is the GeneratorFunction instance.

So in theory:

```
if (!fn.prototype.hasOwnProperty("constructor")) {
    // It's a generator function
}
```

***but***, that would be incredibly unreliable, as people do things like this all the time (although hopefully less so as people start using `class`):

```
function Foo() {
}
Foo.prototype = {
    method: function() {}
};
```

While that `Foo.prototype` object has a `constructor` property, it's inherited, not "own". We could do an `in` check, or a `.constructor == fn` check, but the above would still mis-identify it. You just can't trust `constructor` in the wild, people mess it up too much.

Comment: `toString` is horrible. Please don't recommend this. There are much better ways, such as `instanceof Generator` (where `Generator` is the builtin constructor of generator functions).

Comment: And in any case, [you shouldn't be doing this anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19660350/1048572), it makes no sense to distinguish a generator function from any other (normal) function that returns an iterator (or generator).

Comment: @Bergi: I didn't recommend it. I answered the question, which was *how to*, not *should you*.

Comment: @Bergi: Where is the `Generator` symbol defined by the spec? V8 doesn't know it.

Comment: I see it's no recommendation, I just thought to add a warning would be appropriate. My first comment was about your statement "*I don't think there's a better way than a beefed-up version of `toString`*" which I think is wrong.

Comment: `Generator` was not made a global variable for some reason (not to clutter the scope, probably), but you [can still access it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24901386/1048572)

Comment: It's not an instance property (like `.prototype` is - generator functions are "constructor functions"), it's a [property inherited from `GeneratorFunction.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-generatorfunction.prototype.constructor).  The spec is confusing :-)

Comment: @Bergi: Got it. Yeesh!