# javascript: How to tell if I'm within a generator function?

Tags: javascript

Heyo! I'm playing with `function*`'s and `yield`'s. I've noticed that (In NodeJS) anyway, when I try to call `yield` when I'm not within a `function*`, yield is undefined. Though `yield` is keyword so I can't exactly check if `yield === undefined`.

So what I am asking is, how can I tell if my code is currently running through a `function*`?

Comment: You'll get a lot more help to show the code you're using that is giving you your `yield === undefined`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a variable is a generator function? (e.g function\* yield)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34103051/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-a-generator-function-e-g-function-yield)

Comment: All you need to do is to look at your code and check whether the enclosing function has  a `*` on it. There is no way, and no need, to check for this dynamically in code.

Answer (score 0):

Since generators aren't constructable, you can try using `new GeneratorFunction()`, and it will throw a TypeError in case it's a generator function.

```
function* gen() {
  yield 1;
}

function fn() {
  return 1;
}

function isGenerator(fn) {
  try {
    new fn();
    return false;
  } catch (err) {
    return true;
  }
}

console.log(isGenerator(gen)); // true
console.log(isGenerator(fn)); // false
```

You can also check for `Object.getPrototypeOf(gen)`, and it will return a Generator constructor. Then you can do for example:

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(gen).prototype[Symbol.toStringTag]); // Generator
```

Answer (score 0):

To find out whether you are currently within a [GeneratorFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/GeneratorFunction), you could check the function's constructor:

```js
function* generator() {
  
  // Recommended:
  console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(generator).constructor === Object.getPrototypeOf(function*(){}).constructor);
  
  // Deprecated:
  console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(arguments.callee).constructor === Object.getPrototypeOf(function*(){}).constructor);
}

generator().next();
```