# IsGenerator implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator

I previously relied on the following definition of how to detect a generator:

```
function isGenerator(func) {
    return func instanceof Function && func.constructor.name === 'GeneratorFunction';
}
```

Since then however I came across various other verifications, including checks for `next` and `throw` functions on the prototype.

Is there a way to implement `isGenerator` function to be considered comprehensive within the realm of NodeJS 0.10 - 5.x?

The application in which I intend to use is to pick up any generator (or even iterator), and wrap it up into a promise that would make use of functions `next` and `throw`.

For that I'm using a modified example from [here](https://www.promisejs.org/generators/#both):

```
/////////////////////////////////
// Generator-to-Promise adapter;
function asyncAdapter(generator) {
    return function () {
        var g = generator.apply(this, arguments);

        function handle(result) {
            if (result.done) {
                return Promise.resolve(result.value);
            }
            return Promise.resolve(result.value)
                .then(function (res) {
                    return handle(g.next(res));
                }, function (err) {
                    return handle(g.throw(err));
                });
        }

        return handle(g.next());
    }
}
```

Comment: 0.10 doesn't have native generator functions (or does it?). Do you also want to detect transpiled functions (e.g. with generator)?

Comment: I thought that since generators are built on just the two basic functions - `next` and `throw`, it was possible to have generators in the old Node JS also. But i'm just guessing here.

Comment: A generator function won't have `next` or `throw` IIRC, its iterator will though.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are confusing generator functions with iterators.

Comment: @MinusFour, that is fine. In my application I'm just wrapping up a generator into a promise, relying on just 2 functions - `next` and `throw`. If it still works in that context, that it's all good :)

Comment: @FelixKling, you may be right. I will update my question to explain how I intend to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I previously relied on the following definition of how to detect a generator […]

That doesn't detect generators, it detects generator functions. And you should not *rely* on such a thing, as every function can return a generator.

> Is there a way to implement `isGeneratorFunction` to be considered comprehensive within the realm of NodeJS 0.10 - 5.x?

Yes, there [are a few](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16754956/1048572), next to the `.constructor.name` approach you've shown one can also use `instanceof` or `.toString()`.

> The application in which I intend to use is to pick up any generator (or even iterator)

Don't do this by magic. Just let the user decide whether they want to use generators, and let them call your function explicitly in that case.

Comment: The link you provided is to the mess I referred to. So many different opinions are posted there. I guess I will just have to stick with my old implementation.

Comment: @vitaly-t: The `instanceof GeneratorFunction` approach seems to be the best if you really need to distinguish them. But my point was that you should not need this at all.

Answer (score 0):

[ES 6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-generatorfunctioncreate) says

> ## 9.2.6 GeneratorFunctionCreate (kind, ParameterList, Body, Scope, Strict)
>
> The abstract operation GeneratorFunctionCreate requires the arguments: kind which is one of (Normal, Method), a parameter list production specified by *ParameterList*, a body production specified by *Body*, a Lexical Environment specified by *Scope*, and a Boolean flag *Strict*.
>
> GeneratorFunctionCreate performs the following steps:
>
> 1. Let *functionPrototype* be the intrinsic object **%Generator%**.
> 2. Let *F* be FunctionAllocate(*functionPrototype*, *Strict*, `"generator"`).
> 3. Return FunctionInitialize(*F*, *kind*, *ParameterList*, *Body*, *Scope*).

so you could get close by checking that the prototype
is that appropriate for a generator.  `Object.getPrototypeOf` lets us test whether the value of *functionPrototype* is the builtin %Generator% though proxy objects can control the result of `Object.getPrototypeOf`.  Treating proxies of generators as generators might be a good thing.

```
function isGenerator(functionThatMightBeGenerator) {
  function *nullGenerator() {}
  return (functionThatMightBeGenerator
          &&  Object.getPrototypeOf(functionThatMightBeGenerator)
          === Object.getPrototypeOf(nullGenerator));
}
```

If you're concerned about distinguishing between proxies of generators and generators, you might look at [14.5.14](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation)#6.g.i.  That requires that class declaration forbids generators as super types so provides a direct check whether the *FunctionKind* internal slot is `"generator"`.

This is probably overkill, but something like

```
function isGeneratorAndProbablyNotProxyThereof(functionThatMightBeGenerator) {
  function *nullGenerator() {}
  if (!functionThatMightBeGenerator
      || (Object.getPrototypeOf(functionThatMightBeGenerator)
          !== Object.getPrototypeOf(nullGenerator))) {
    return false;
  }
  function defineAndThrowawaySubClass(superType) {
    class C extends superType {}
  }
  let isGenerator = false;
  try {
    defineAndThrowawaySubClass(functionThatMightBeGenerator);
  } catch (e) {
    isGenerator = e instanceof TypeError;
  }
  return isGenerator;
}
```

should do it though a sufficiently motivated proxy writer could probably spoof this too.