# break terminates the iterator in for ... of loop

Tags: javascript, iterator, for-of-loop

Why does the `break` terminates the iterator returned by foo? We use `break`   to terminate the loop, but why does it kill the iterator too? Is it just how it is, or am I missing a point?

```js
function* foo(){
      yield 1;
      yield 2;
}

let myIterator = foo()
    
for (let o of myIterator) {
   console.log(o);
   break; // closes iterator, triggers return
}

for(let of of myIterator) {
   console.log(o)
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: you miss: `foo()` returns an iterator and outside of the loop it is not known.

Comment: It breaks the loop so the iterator is not iterated any further. The `for` controls the iterator, not the other way around.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I did not even asked the question properly. Can you please check now, I updated the question. @NinaScholz I realize that it returns an iterator. But when I break the first for ... of loop, the iterator itself is terminated, and the second for ... of loop does not iterate. This is what I am asking why. Can you please see now?

Comment: now it looks like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47238463/how-do-i-reuse-a-generator-in-es6-javascript-in-for-loops

Comment: Yes, I clearly missed the point that it was not about break, but about not being able to use the same generator twice. Thanks a lot @NinaScholz!